# Is it possible to send SysRq commands with a barcode scanner?

Tags: linux, barcode-scanner

We have a kiosk application that runs matchbox on top of linux, and has only a barcode scanner for input (no keyboard). It would be great to be able to print a barcode that--when scanned--sent commands like `SysRq R` etc, so that one could REISUB without having to disassemble the unit.

If there is not an existing way, could you patch the barcode driver to interpret a certain set of symbols and initiate the sequence?

Comment: I would add a SysRq Tag, but my rep is not sufficient to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need SysRq?  Is the machine actually wedging itself or are you just trying to reboot cleanly?  Why not just put a "reboot" command into whatever protocol you're using?  What's wrong with simply doing a hard power cycle?

Comment: It would just be an easy, universal solution to rebooting cleanly without the need to disassemble or have the power button too accessible. The software itself is delivered via Ajax, so it can't do things like reboot. We would have to go lower level.

Comment: OK, so your client that sees the scanner key events is a browser, so you can't directly reboot there.  But you control the device and deployment, right?  How about running a trivial web server on the box (with appropriate firewalling to make sure it's limited to local clients!) with a CGI script that runs /sbin/shutdown appropriately?